# vanilla tilt js why it doesnt work in browser,but work in stackovervlow snippet?

Tags: javascript, css-animations, vanilla-forums

[image]its my firtst time using vanilla tilt js for 3d animation on my site.But i just followed all tutorial in internet,and has matched each code line of code with the comand and tutorial from [vanilla-tilt.js](https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/) and make sure each tutorial from maker that i tried properly.But it doesnt work in my browser. and this is my code and the result in browser. **i also tried on live preview extension on vs code,but hve same result it doesnt work..**.thanks:)

[image: this is the result in browser but still doesnt workin]

```js
var VanillaTilt=function(){"use strict";class t{constructor(e,i={}){if(!(e instanceof Node))throw"Can't initialize VanillaTilt because "+e+" is not a Node.";this.width=null,this.height=null,this.clientWidth=null,this.clientHeight=null,this.left=null,this.top=null,this.gammazero=null,this.betazero=null,this.lastgammazero=null,this.lastbetazero=null,this.transitionTimeout=null,this.updateCall=null,this.event=null,this.updateBind=this.update.bind(this),this.resetBind=this.reset.bind(this),this.element=e,this.settings=this.extendSettings(i),this.reverse=this.settings.reverse?-1:1,this.glare=t.isSettingTrue(this.settings.glare),this.glarePrerender=t.isSettingTrue(this.settings["glare-prerender"]),this.fullPageListening=t.isSettingTrue(this.settings["full-page-listening"]),this.gyroscope=t.isSettingTrue(this.settings.gyroscope),this.gyroscopeSamples=this.settings.gyroscopeSamples,this.elementListener=this.getElementListener(),this.glare&&this.prepareGlare(),this.fullPageListening&&this.updateClientSize(),this.addEventListeners(),this.reset(),this.updateInitialPosition()}static isSettingTrue(t){return""===t||!0===t||1===t}getElementListener(){if(this.fullPageListening)return window.document;if("string"==typeof this.settings["mouse-event-element"]){const t=document.querySelector(this.settings["mouse-event-element"]);if(t)return t}return this.settings["mouse-event-element"]instanceof Node?this.settings["mouse-event-element"]:this.element}addEventListeners(){this.onMouseEnterBind=this.onMouseEnter.bind(this),this.onMouseMoveBind=this.onMouseMove.bind(this),this.onMouseLeaveBind=this.onMouseLeave.bind(this),this.onWindowResizeBind=this.onWindowResize.bind(this),this.onDeviceOrientationBind=this.onDeviceOrientation.bind(this),this.elementListener.addEventListener("mouseenter",this.onMouseEnterBind),this.elementListener.addEventListener("mouseleave",this.onMouseLeaveBind),this.elementListener.addEventListener("mousemove",this.onMouseMoveBind),(this.glare||this.fullPageListening)&&window.addEventListener("resize",this.onWindowResizeBind),this.gyroscope&&window.addEventListener("deviceorientation",this.onDeviceOrientationBind)}removeEventListeners(){this.elementListener.removeEventListener("mouseenter",this.onMouseEnterBind),this.elementListener.removeEventListener("mouseleave",this.onMouseLeaveBind),this.elementListener.removeEventListener("mousemove",this.onMouseMoveBind),this.gyroscope&&window.removeEventListener("deviceorientation",this.onDeviceOrientationBind),(this.glare||this.fullPageListening)&&window.removeEventListener("resize",this.onWindowResizeBind)}destroy(){clearTimeout(this.transitionTimeout),null!==this.updateCall&&cancelAnimationFrame(this.updateCall),this.reset(),this.removeEventListeners(),this.element.vanillaTilt=null,delete this.element.vanillaTilt,this.element=null}onDeviceOrientation(t){if(null===t.gamma||null===t.beta)return;this.updateElementPosition(),this.gyroscopeSamples>0&&(this.lastgammazero=this.gammazero,this.lastbetazero=this.betazero,null===this.gammazero?(this.gammazero=t.gamma,this.betazero=t.beta):(this.gammazero=(t.gamma+this.lastgammazero)/2,this.betazero=(t.beta+this.lastbetazero)/2),this.gyroscopeSamples-=1);const e=this.settings.gyroscopeMaxAngleX-this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleX,i=this.settings.gyroscopeMaxAngleY-this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleY,s=e/this.width,n=i/this.height,l=(t.gamma-(this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleX+this.gammazero))/s,a=(t.beta-(this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleY+this.betazero))/n;null!==this.updateCall&&cancelAnimationFrame(this.updateCall),this.event={clientX:l+this.left,clientY:a+this.top},this.updateCall=requestAnimationFrame(this.updateBind)}onMouseEnter(){this.updateElementPosition(),this.element.style.willChange="transform",this.setTransition()}onMouseMove(t){null!==this.updateCall&&cancelAnimationFrame(this.updateCall),this.event=t,this.updateCall=requestAnimationFrame(this.updateBind)}onMouseLeave(){this.setTransition(),this.settings.reset&&requestAnimationFrame(this.resetBind)}reset(){this.event={clientX:this.left+this.width/2,clientY:this.top+this.height/2},this.element&&this.element.style&&(this.element.style.transform=`perspective(${this.settings.perspective}px) `+"rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1)"),this.resetGlare()}resetGlare(){this.glare&&(this.glareElement.style.transform="rotate(180deg) translate(-50%, -50%)",this.glareElement.style.opacity="0")}updateInitialPosition(){if(0===this.settings.startX&&0===this.settings.startY)return;this.onMouseEnter(),this.fullPageListening?this.event={clientX:(this.settings.startX+this.settings.max)/(2*this.settings.max)*this.clientWidth,clientY:(this.settings.startY+this.settings.max)/(2*this.settings.max)*this.clientHeight}:this.event={clientX:this.left+(this.settings.startX+this.settings.max)/(2*this.settings.max)*this.width,clientY:this.top+(this.settings.startY+this.settings.max)/(2*this.settings.max)*this.height};let t=this.settings.scale;this.settings.scale=1,this.update(),this.settings.scale=t,this.resetGlare()}getValues(){let t,e;return this.fullPageListening?(t=this.event.clientX/this.clientWidth,e=this.event.clientY/this.clientHeight):(t=(this.event.clientX-this.left)/this.width,e=(this.event.clientY-this.top)/this.height),t=Math.min(Math.max(t,0),1),e=Math.min(Math.max(e,0),1),{tiltX:(this.reverse*(this.settings.max-t*this.settings.max*2)).toFixed(2),tiltY:(this.reverse*(e*this.settings.max*2-this.settings.max)).toFixed(2),percentageX:100*t,percentageY:100*e,angle:Math.atan2(this.event.clientX-(this.left+this.width/2),-(this.event.clientY-(this.top+this.height/2)))*(180/Math.PI)}}updateElementPosition(){let t=this.element.getBoundingClientRect();this.width=this.element.offsetWidth,this.height=this.element.offsetHeight,this.left=t.left,this.top=t.top}update(){let t=this.getValues();this.element.style.transform="perspective("+this.settings.perspective+"px) rotateX("+("x"===this.settings.axis?0:t.tiltY)+"deg) rotateY("+("y"===this.settings.axis?0:t.tiltX)+"deg) scale3d("+this.settings.scale+", "+this.settings.scale+", "+this.settings.scale+")",this.glare&&(this.glareElement.style.transform=`rotate(${t.angle}deg) translate(-50%, -50%)`,this.glareElement.style.opacity=`${t.percentageY*this.settings["max-glare"]/100}`),this.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("tiltChange",{detail:t})),this.updateCall=null}prepareGlare(){if(!this.glarePrerender){const t=document.createElement("div");t.classList.add("js-tilt-glare");const e=document.createElement("div");e.classList.add("js-tilt-glare-inner"),t.appendChild(e),this.element.appendChild(t)}this.glareElementWrapper=this.element.querySelector(".js-tilt-glare"),this.glareElement=this.element.querySelector(".js-tilt-glare-inner"),this.glarePrerender||(Object.assign(this.glareElementWrapper.style,{position:"absolute",top:"0",left:"0",width:"100%",height:"100%",overflow:"hidden","pointer-events":"none"}),Object.assign(this.glareElement.style,{position:"absolute",top:"50%",left:"50%","pointer-events":"none","background-image":"linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)",transform:"rotate(180deg) translate(-50%, -50%)","transform-origin":"0% 0%",opacity:"0"}),this.updateGlareSize())}updateGlareSize(){if(this.glare){const t=2*(this.element.offsetWidth>this.element.offsetHeight?this.element.offsetWidth:this.element.offsetHeight);Object.assign(this.glareElement.style,{width:`${t}px`,height:`${t}px`})}}updateClientSize(){this.clientWidth=window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth,this.clientHeight=window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight}onWindowResize(){this.updateGlareSize(),this.updateClientSize()}setTransition(){clearTimeout(this.transitionTimeout),this.element.style.transition=this.settings.speed+"ms "+this.settings.easing,this.glare&&(this.glareElement.style.transition=`opacity ${this.settings.speed}ms ${this.settings.easing}`),this.transitionTimeout=setTimeout(()=>{this.element.style.transition="",this.glare&&(this.glareElement.style.transition="")},this.settings.speed)}extendSettings(t){let e={reverse:!1,max:15,startX:0,startY:0,perspective:1e3,easing:"cubic-bezier(.03,.98,.52,.99)",scale:1,speed:300,transition:!0,axis:null,glare:!1,"max-glare":1,"glare-prerender":!1,"full-page-listening":!1,"mouse-event-element":null,reset:!0,gyroscope:!0,gyroscopeMinAngleX:-45,gyroscopeMaxAngleX:45,gyroscopeMinAngleY:-45,gyroscopeMaxAngleY:45,gyroscopeSamples:10},i={};for(var s in e)if(s in t)i[s]=t[s];else if(this.element.hasAttribute("data-tilt-"+s)){let t=this.element.getAttribute("data-tilt-"+s);try{i[s]=JSON.parse(t)}catch(e){i[s]=t}}else i[s]=e[s];return i}static init(e,i){e instanceof Node&&(e=[e]),e instanceof NodeList&&(e=[].slice.call(e)),e instanceof Array&&e.forEach(e=>{"vanillaTilt"in e||(e.vanillaTilt=new t(e,i))})}}return"undefined"!=typeof document&&(window.VanillaTilt=t,t.init(document.querySelectorAll("[data-tilt]"))),t}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>coba tilt.js</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
.kotak{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: flex;
}
.kotak h3{
    margin: auto;
}
</style>  
</head>
  <body>
    <script src="vanilla-tilt.min.js" integrity="sha512-K9tDZvc8nQXR1DMuT97sct9f40dilGp97vx7EXjswJA+/mKqJZ8vcZLifZDP+9t08osMLuiIjd4jZ0SM011Q+w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">

    </script>
    <!-- <h1>my judul</h1> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="kotak" data-tilt data-tilt-max="50" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-perspective="500">
            <h3>tulisanku</h3>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ive restart my pc,and my vs code and so on my browser.but still nothing different from before.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is you need to add transform styles to your container element and child `h3` - assuming you want a 3d style parallax effect.

You also need to add the following js to your page to initialize the effect for your element:

```
VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelector('.kotak'), {
    max: 25,
    speed: 400
});
```

Just add the following css to your elements and the effect should work:

```
.kotak{
    // add these two styles  
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: perspective(1000px);
}

.kotak h3{
  // add this style
  transform: translateZ(20px);
}
```

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nL3e62wq/) for reference.

Comment: yaa,ive also tried that method but its still the same.. :(

Comment: on vanilla tilt js site tutorial,they said there is 2 ways to do that i.e **easy way** and **js way**.ive try all that way. :(

Comment: You're not calling VanillaTilt in your code. Look at the example I provided and you'll see it being used. Just hit the run button in the upper left corner and hover over your target.

Comment: woh iya...im forget..wkwkwk..thanks bro...if you want come to surabaya,indonesia,you call me..wkwkw thanks...actually this is very easy stuf but,why tomorrow couldnt,cause im litle tired maybe...wkwkk...may i can help you sometimes ..